# How to add multiple pictures to custom tableviewcells with tag or identifier

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I want to add pictures from an `NSMutableArray` to custom cells in a tableview. There will be four or more images in every cell. So here's my problem:

If I refer to `indexPath.row` the custom cells would look like these:

> cell1: picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4
>   cell2: picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5
>   cell3: picture3, picture4, picture5, picture6

but I want:

> cell1: picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4
>   cell2: picture5, picture6, picture7, picture8
>   cell3: picture9, picture10, picture11, picture12

I'm new to xCode and I don't see a good solution.

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCustomCell";

    ImageCustomCell *cell = (ImageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ImageCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {

            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {

                cell = (ImageCustomCell *) currentObject;

            break;
            }
        }
    }
// here i get the indexPath.row for every cell and add +1 - +3 to it to get the next image, but every new cell just get +1, not +4
    cell.imageForCell.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageForCell2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];
    cell.imageForCell3.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]];
    cell.imageForCell4.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that while `indexPath.row` increases by one per call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you are coding as if it increased by 4. Of course, `UITableView` row index increments should and will remain at one per row, so you have to find a different approach.

You need to find a function that maps `indexPath` to the index in the `imagePathArray` corresponding to the image you want to put leftmost in the cell for the the row described by `indexPath`. Once you find that index, the remaining three images are just 1, 2, and 3 elements offset from that.

Since this isn't tagged "homework" I guess I'll just give you the answer: it's the row multiplied by the number of images per row. You can take that as you like, or use this bit of code. Hasn't been compiled or tested, if you can't work out any typos or bugs on your own let me know.

Implement a method like this:

```
- (NSArray *)imagePathsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger imagePathArrayStartingIndex = indexPath.row * IMAGES_PER_ROW;
    NSRange imagePathArrayIndexRange = NSMakeRange(imagePathArrayStartingIndex, IMAGES_PER_ROW);
    NSIndexSet *imagePathArrayIndexes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:imagePathArrayIndexRange];
    NSArray *imagePathsForRow = [imagePathArray objectsAtIndexes:imagePathArrayIndexes];
    return imagePathsForRow;
}
```

Then change the lines where you set your cell images in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSArray *imagePathsForRow = [self imagePathsForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageForCell.image  = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathsForRow objectAtIndex:0]];
cell.imageForCell2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathsForRow objectAtIndex:1]];
cell.imageForCell3.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathsForRow objectAtIndex:2]];
cell.imageForCell4.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathsForRow objectAtIndex:3]];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're welcome! Did this help resolve the issue or do you still need further help?

Comment: yeah, helped me very much. but it's simpler then that: cell.imageForCell.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*1)]]; and
cell.imageForCell.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imagePathArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)]]; and so on..